# Deleting multiple entries in a SQL database using a Python script

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, sql-delete

I'm new to Python and SQL, but I need to delete multiple entries in a table on a remote server. I would also prefer to preserve the input structure of a function I was given because it is used in codes of other colleagues.

I came up with a solution that does the job similar to the one presented below. I deliberately avoided using any sort of `executemany()` methods because (if I am not mistaken,) they can be terribly slow.

```
import sqlalchemy as sa
import urllib

def delete_rows(tablename, colnames, data):
    """
    tablename - name of db table with dbname. like RiskData..factors
    colnames - column names to use as keys in deletion
    data - a list of tuples, a tuple per row, number of elements in each
           tuple must is the same as number of column names
    """

    # Connection details
    engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://some_server")
    connection = self.engine.connect()

    # Data has to be a list - throw an exception if it is not
    if (not (type(data) is list)):
        raise Exception('Data must be a list');

    #  assemble one long query statement
    query = "DELETE " + tablename + " WHERE "
    query_dp = "or (" + " = '{}' and ".join(colnames) + "= '{}') "
    query_tail = ""
    for record_entries in data:
        query_tail += query_dp.format(*record_entries)
    query += query_tail[3:-1]
    connection.execute(query)

    connection.close()
```

I would like to ask whether this solution is inefficient and will be slow for a large amounts of data? If so, what would a more elegant solution be?

Comment: you are matching multiple columns in the `DELETE` statement? What if I give data=1 and columns = `['id', 'street_num']`? Would it delete all rows with either id=1 and street_num=1? Is that really what you want?

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to use ORM? eg, Django?

Comment: @hansaplast, sorry if some details of my problem were lacking. I am trying to delete entries. If one tries the inputs you suggested, then an error would occur.

If say I were to use an input like `data = [(1,2),(3,4)]` and `colnames = ['id','street']` then it would delete 2 rows with (id=1,street=2) and (id=3,street=4).

Comment: A tiny bit of improvement: use format interpolation on your definition of query, i.e.  `"DELETE {} WHERE".format(tablename)`

The real questions for performance are 'how often' and 'how many' and 'what RDBMS', in my opinion.

Comment: @style I am still learning about ORM's... Would they do anything more sophisticated under the hood?

Comment: ORM are just an abstraction layer. eventually it will run a query.. it will prevent SQL injections, bad parameters, etc.

Comment: @BenjaminHicks thanks for the small suggestion. Regarding your (possibly rhetorical) questions: MS SQL Server is used, but not often and a lot at a time. Like hundred thousand entries with no more than 10 columns is within the realm of possibilities.

Comment: @J.K. right,  I though you were joining with an `OR` but you join them with `AND`, so this looks good. Still, why do you put the `OR` at the start and then cut it away again with `[3:]`?

Comment: @J.K. Not rhetorical at all! I thought someone who knew the specifics of your RDBMS might be able to say if this would hit any performance bottlenecks in the specific implementation and given a specific number of records in the query. Premature optimization bad, etc. etc.

Comment: Please, for the love of everything that is holy, do not use string formatting for passing values to queries. That's what placeholders/bindparams are for. Pass a query and its arguments **separately** to `execute()`. In other words don't treat your data as code. Someone else might do that too... Also, you're using SQLAlchemy, which is an excellent Pythonic query builder, no strings required! (mostly)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about speed, but as far as elegance goes, [don't use string formatting for passing values to SQL queries](https://xkcd.com/327/). Since you're already using SQLAlchemy, you can leverage its query building capabilities:

```
def delete_rows(tablename, colnames, data):
    """
    tablename - name of db table with dbname. like RiskData..factors
    colnames - column names to use as keys in deletion
    data - a list of tuples, a tuple per row, number of elements in each
           tuple must is the same as number of column names
    """
    # Data has to be a list - throw an exception if it is not
    if not isinstance(data, list):
        raise Exception('Data must be a list');

    # Connection details
    engine = sa.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc://some_server")

    # Create `column()` objects for producing bindparams
    cols = [sa.column(name) for name in colnames]
    # Create a list of predicates, to be joined with OR
    preds = []
    for record_entries in data:
        pred = sa.and_(*[c == e for c, e in zip(cols, record_entries)])
        preds.append(pred)
    # assemble one long query statement
    query = sa.table(tablename).delete().where(sa.or_(*preds))

    with engine.begin() as connection:
        connection.execute(query)
```

Whether or not `executemany()` is slow depends on the DB-API driver in use. In case of `pyodbc` [this used to be true](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/issues/120), but [there's been work to improve it](https://github.com/mkleehammer/pyodbc/wiki/Features-beyond-the-DB-API#fast_executemany).